# Botão de Link no Slideshow com html, css e Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Seguinte, estou com o site praticamente pronto, apenas preciso que meus banners tenham uma forma de acessar os *html* que fiz. 
Problema que os botoes que adicionei estão seguindo a configuração do *js*, mas não funcionam o clique, eu sei que preciso habilitar isso no *js*, mas não tenho ideia de como.

Só para avisar, *js* não é meu forte e parte do código (boa parte) eu copiei de um modelo de *slideshow*, então só preciso de uma ajuda pra habilitar isso.

Código do JS:

```
var slideIndex,slides,dots,captionText;
function initGallery(){
    slideIndex = 0;
    slides=document.getElementsByClassName("imageHolder");
    slides[slideIndex].style.opacity=1;

    captionText=document.querySelector(".captionTextHolder .captionText");
    captionText.innerText=slides[slideIndex].querySelector(".captionText").innerText;

//disable nextPrevBtn if slide count is one
if(slides.length<2){
    var nextPrevBtns=document.querySelector(".leftArrow,.rightArrow");
    nextPrevBtns.style.display="none";
    for (i = 0; i < nextPrevBtn.length; i++) {
        nextPrevBtn[i].style.display="none";
    }
}

//add dots
dots=[];
var dotsContainer=document.getElementById("dotsContainer"),i;
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    var dot=document.createElement("span");
    dot.classList.add("dots");
    dotsContainer.append(dot);
    dot.setAttribute("onclick","moveSlide("+i+")");
    dots.push(dot);
}
dots[slideIndex].classList.add("active");
}
initGallery();
function plusSlides(n) {
    moveSlide(slideIndex+n);
}
function moveSlide(n){
    var i;
    var current,next;
    var moveSlideAnimClass={
          forCurrent:"",
          forNext:""
    };
    var slideTextAnimClass;
    if(n>slideIndex) {
        if(n >= slides.length){n=0;}
        moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent="moveLeftCurrentSlide";
        moveSlideAnimClass.forNext="moveLeftNextSlide";
        slideTextAnimClass="slideTextFromTop";
    }else if(n<slideIndex){
        if(n<0){n=slides.length-1;}
        moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent="moveRightCurrentSlide";
        moveSlideAnimClass.forNext="moveRightPrevSlide";
        slideTextAnimClass="slideTextFromBottom";
    }

    if(n!=slideIndex){
        next = slides[n];
        current=slides[slideIndex];
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].className = "imageHolder";
            slides[i].style.opacity=0;
            dots[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        current.classList.add(moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent);
        next.classList.add(moveSlideAnimClass.forNext);
        dots[n].classList.add("active");
        slideIndex=n;
        captionText.style.display="none";
        captionText.className="captionText "+slideTextAnimClass;
        captionText.innerText=slides[n].querySelector(".captionText").innerText;
        captionText.style.display="block";
    }

}
var timer=null;
function setTimer(){
    timer=setInterval(function () {
        plusSlides(1) ;
    },3000);
}
setTimer();
function playPauseSlides() {
    var playPauseBtn=document.getElementById("playPause");
    if
        (timer==null){
        setTimer();
    }else{
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer=null;
    }
}
```

Código do HTML onde ele está vinculado:

```
    <div class="galleryContainer" id="playPause" onmouseover="playPauseSlides()" onmouseout="playPauseSlides()">
            <div class="slideShowContainer">
                <div onclick="plusSlides(-1)" class="nextPrevBtn leftArrow"><span class="arrow arrowLeft"></span></div>
                <div onclick="plusSlides(1)" class="nextPrevBtn rightArrow"><span class="arrow arrowRight"></span></div>
                <div class="captionTextHolder"><p class="captionText slideTextFromTop"></p></div>
                <div class="imageHolder">
                    <img src="_media/rcp.jpg">
                    <p class="captionText"><strong>ONE</strong> 
                                             descrição aqui</p>
                    <p class="btn"><a href="#">Link</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="imageHolder">
                    <img src="_media/cirurgia.jpg">
                    <p class="captionText"><strong>DUO</strong> 
                                            descrição aqui</p>
                    <p class="btn"><a href="#">Link</a></p>                     
                </div>
                <div class="imageHolder">
                    <img src="_media/segurorenda.jpg">
                    <p class="captionText"><strong>TRE</strong>
                                             descrição aqui</p>
                    <p class="btn"><a href="#">Link</a></p>                      
                </div>
                <div class="imageHolder">
                    <img src="_media/viagem.jpg">
                    <p class="captionText"><strong>FOR</strong>
                                             descrição aqui</p>
                    <p class="btn"><a href="#">Link</a></p>                      
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="dotsContainer"></div>
            <script src="_js/myScript.js"></script>
        </div>
```

CSS:
~
    @keyframes shake {
  0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
  30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
  40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
  80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    src: url(https://fonts.google.com/?query=titi&selection.family=Titillium+Web);
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    font-family: Titillium Web;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* until here, menu settings, all right here */

/*  ----------------------------  */ 
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
}
/*  this will fix top the menu, and keep it all lengt of page  */

.menu{
    background-color: darkred;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    /*  down here will center the menu (or another content)  */ 
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

-moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

```
 -o-box-shadow: 0 4px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    box-shadow: 0 4px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

}
```

.menu ul{
    left: 500px;
    margin: 0 0 0 250px;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.menu ul li a{
    color: #f7f7f7;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    margin: 0px -2px;

/*  down is compatibility transition  */ 
    -webkit-transition: color .15s;

-moz-transition: color .15s;

```
 -o-transition: color .15s;

    transition: color .15s;

    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
```

-moz-transition: background-color 0.3s;

```
 -o-transition: background-color 0.3s;

    transition: background-color 0.3s;
```

}

.menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #AD0000;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}

/*  --------------------------------------------------  */ 
.menu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    color: white;
    top: 115px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

```
-webkit-transition: all .1s .1s;
```

-moz-transition: all .1s .1s;

```
 -o-transition: all .1s .1s;

    transition: all .1s .1s;
```

}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 140px;
    opacity: 1;
}

/* until here is the dropdown settings  */

/* here is the settings for the triangle over the dropdown  */ 
.menu ul li ul:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-color: darkred;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent darkred transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 80px;
}

.menu ul li ul li {
    position: relative;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li a {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    color: #707070;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    color: darkred;
}

.menu ul li ul li a {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.logo-color {
    position: absolute;
    left: 220px;
    max-width: 200px;
    top: 32px;
}

/*banner*/

.galleryContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    position: relative;
}

.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder .captionText{
    display: none;
}

.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .leftArrow,.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .rightArrow{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #00000036;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: background 0.5s;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .rightArrow{
    left: auto;
    right: 40px;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .leftArrow:hover,.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .rightArrow:hover{
    background: #000000a8;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.galleryContainer .arrow{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid white;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.galleryContainer .arrow.arrowLeft{
    transform: rotateZ(-135deg);
    left: 5px;
}
.galleryContainer .arrow.arrowRight{
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    left: -5px;
}

.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer>.captionTextHolder{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 750px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #00000060;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    margin-top: -50px;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer>.captionTextHolder>.captionText{
    margin: 0;
}

.galleryContainer #dotsContainer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -60px;
    z-index: 2;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:background-color 0.5s;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots:hover,.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots.active{
    background-color: #717171;;
}

.galleryContainer .moveLeftCurrentSlide{
    animation-name: moveLeftCurrent;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

}
.galleryContainer .moveLeftNextSlide{
    animation-name: moveLeftNext;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@keyframes moveLeftCurrent {
    from {margin-left: 0;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: -100%;opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes moveLeftNext {
    from {margin-left: 100%;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: 0%;opacity: 1;}
}

.galleryContainer .moveRightCurrentSlide{
    animation-name: moveRightCurrent;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
.galleryContainer .moveRightPrevSlide{
    animation-name: moveRightPrev;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@keyframes moveRightCurrent {
    from {margin-left: 0;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: 100%;opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes moveRightPrev {
    from {margin-left: -100%;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: 0%;opacity: 1;}
}
.slideTextFromBottom {
    animation-name: slideTextFromBottom;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@keyframes slideTextFromBottom {
    from {opacity: 0;margin-top: 100px}
    to {opacity: 1;margin-top: 0px;}
}
.slideTextFromTop {
    animation-name: slideTextFromTop;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@keyframes slideTextFromTop {
    from {opacity: 0;margin-top: -100px}
    to {opacity: 1;margin-top: 0px;}
}

/* --- end of banners */

.separator {
    border-right: 3px solid darkred;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: -33%;
    height: 120px;
    top: 815px;
}

.prop {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.prop h1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: 250px;
    padding: 20px; 
    float: left;
    top: 40px;
    font-size: 20pt;
    line-height: 25pt;
    text-align: right;
    color: #707070;
}

.prop h2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 20px; 
    top: -13px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    color: darkred;
}

.prop p {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: -33%;
    right: 10%;
    border-right: 10px;
    padding: 20px; 
    float: right;
    text-align: justify;
    top: -8px;
    color: #707070;
    line-height: 23px;
}

.container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    width: 1400px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position: relative;
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
}

.containeritem {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.containeritem img {
    width: 150px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.containeritem img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.mdrt {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.imagehands {
    background: url(../_media/handshake.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

## mdrtmember {

```
position: absolute;
top: 1500px;
left: 800px;
width: 700px;
z-index: 1;
```

}

.mdrt h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 200px;
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: white;
}

.mdrt p {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    top: 40%;
    left: 200px;
    color: white;
}

.demais {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 3%;
    left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    top: 150px;
    grid-row-gap: 12px;
}

.demais h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 38%;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: darkred;
    top: -110px;
}

.demais img {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

.demais img:hover {
    animation: shake 0.3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 10s;
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #202020;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.footeritem {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    left: 5%;
    top: 20px;
}

.footeritem p {
    color: #808080;
}

.footeritem2 {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    left: 56%;
    top: 20px;
}

.footeritem2 p {
    color: #808080;
}

/*

A EMPRESA

*/

.empresa {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkred;
    height: 100px;
    top: -6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.empresa h3 {
    left: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    top: 18px;
}

.empresa p {
    left: 1300px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    top: 28px;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

.empresa p a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.empresa-texto {
    left: 60px;
    max-width: 1450px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
}

.empresa-texto h1 {
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: darkred;
}

.empresa-texto p{
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #707070;
    text-align: justify;
}

/*

equipe

*/

.equipe {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 2%;
    left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto ;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto ;
    top: 50px;
    grid-row-gap: 45px;
}

.equipe img {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

/*

loja virtual

*/

.loja {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
}

.loja h1 {
    font-size: 20pt;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    color: darkred;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.loja h2 {
    font-size: 15pt;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 600px;
    color: #707070;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.pulse {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: darkred;
    padding: 5px 50px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
    left: 50%;
    top: 690px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

.pulse a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25pt;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.loja img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.pulse:hover {
  animation: none;
  background-color: #ad0000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(128, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(128, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(128, 0, 0, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(128, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(128, 0, 0, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(128, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}

/* produtos */

.produtos {
    position: relative;
    width: 1400px;
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    top: 30px;
    border-bottom: 30px;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    display: grid;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-row-gap: 25px;

}

.proditem{
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.proditem p {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.proditemimg {
    position: relative;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 390px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    top: 4px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.proditemimg img{
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 390px;
    height: 300px;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.proditemimg:hover img{
    transform: scale(1.3) rotate(10deg);
}

.prodlink {
    position: relative;
    width: 390px;
    height: 30px;
    top: -155px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: block;
    background: darkred;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.prodlink a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        vertical-align: middle;
}

.prodlink:hover {
    background-color: #ad0000;
}

.prodlink:hover .prodlink a {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* premiações */

.premiacao {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin: 50px 0;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.premiacao h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    color: darkred;
    text-align: right;
    right: 50px;
}

.premiacao h2 {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    color: #707070;
    text-align: right;
    right: 50px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.divider {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 50px;
    top: -40px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid darkred;
}

.premiacao p {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    width: 1000px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 50px;
    direction: rtl;
    float: right;
}

.premimg img {
    height: 400px;
    top: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* contato */

.btn {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: darkred;
    padding: 5px 50px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 500px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

.btn a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25pt;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
  animation: none;
  background-color: #ad0000;
}

~
agradeço muito se conseguirem um codiguinho maroto!

Comment: Você quer clicar em um link e ser redirecionado para outra página?

Comment: isso, vou fazer um slideshow com os produtos da empresa, ai para que esses links vão para cada produto classificado no slide

Comment: Você já tentou passar o link da página do produto dentro do  href="#".

Comment: sim, já tentei várias formas, criando um <p> com <a href>, tentei href no class="imageHolder", tentei por também direto na imagem como fiz com a logo principal, colocando o <img> dentro de um <a>, eu vi algumas pessoas dizendo na gringa que precisa ser feito isso pelo js, porém não disseram como e sugeriram o jQuery, mas nao quero misturar JS com jQuery.

Comment: Você pode resumir seu código em: <a class="btn" href="produto.html">Link para a página do produto</a>

Comment: tentei mas nao deu certo, simplesmente some o botão e nada clicável

Comment: Esse link pode te ajudar a entender o porque não é legal usar a tag <a> dentro de um botão:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280684/nesting-a-inside-button-doesnt-work-in-firefox

Comment: Insira seu código css na pergunta para ficar melhor para eu te ajudar.

Comment: Eu troquei o <button> por um <p>, ficou melhor inclusive no site, só achei que iria funcionar melhor nessa parte com o <button> mas me enganei.

Comment: todo o CSS ou só a parte onde criei a parte para linkar com o botão?

Comment: NÃO se deve colocar <a> dentro de um <button>. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5/6393863 Você pode fazer assim também: <p class="btn"> <a href="#">Link</a> </p>

Comment: Todo o arquivo css

Comment: foi como eu havia feito anteriormente em outra parte do html, agora retornei para essa formatação, vou atualizar o codigo...

Comment: só preciso conseguir colocar aqui o código da forma certa, mas parece que nao peguei o jeito ainda kk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procure no seu CSS esse trecho de código

```
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer>.captionTextHolder {
 .
 .
 .
 }
```

E substitua por esse

```
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer>.captionTextHolder {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        color: white;
        font-size: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #00000060;
        background: transparent;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
}
```

Explicação: A sua div

```
<div class="captionTextHolder"><p class="captionText slideTextFromTop"></p></div>
```

estava cobrindo o os slides por isso vc não estava conseguindo clicar no botão.

Comment: Caraca deu certo, nem acredito que eu mesmo fiz essa coisa errada :'D